# Grids in Java- Equivalent

Tags: java

Is there any grid equivalent object in java ?
I tried using j tables but they don't have all the functionalities needed.
in C# there is a grid object which saves a lot of work. i was wondering if there is any similar object in java.

Comment: I can't answer your question since I don't know C# (like many other Java users). It would be helpful if you could add more details.Like which functionalities you are missing exactly.

Comment: Please add details of what the C# grid object gives you - is it a datastructure, widget etc?

Comment: The "grid" is most likely the Windows Forms Grid, which btw is not part of the C# language but is a part of the .net GUI Framework called Windows Forms. And I think you won't find 1:1 interchangeable (functionality-wise) classes in Java nor Swing/AWT/SWT ... whatever.

Comment: [GridPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no grid like data structure or collection available in Java. Though you can implement a grid like structure in Java with help of a two-dimensional array. 
In case of AWT you might want to use the [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) class. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Definitively the equivalent is JTable, however, if you're trying to create functionalities seems to Grid in C#, you will need to do a little bit extra effort, with swing you should focus on events and add the corresponding listeners in order to add the desired features on it.